# Ext.app.ViewController, Point More than One Component to A Single Handler

Tags: javascript, extjs

In Ext JS 5.*, there is a new controller type to fit into Sencha's modeling of MVC: [Ext.app.ViewController](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.app.ViewController-method-control). I am specifically interested in the linked `control` method, which according to the doc.s. utilizes `Ext.ComponentQuery` to "select" the components to which to listen.

A typical routing in `this.control({})` looks like:

```
this.control({  
    'componentselector' : {  
        'event' : this.doSomething  
     }  
//....
```

Is it possible to route multiple components' 'event' to the same method ***on one line***, e.g.:

```
this.control({  
    'componentselector', 'anothercomponentselector' : {  
        'event' : this.doSomething  
     }  
//....
```

Really, this question is more about syntactic sugar than anything else.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

Comment: @AlexTokarev, thanks. I read through the docks before posting this question. I hadn't looked at "Query Examples", more closely. I thought that would be something addressed not in an example, but elsewhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
'componentselector, anothercomponentselector': {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had seen it somewhere! I will accept your question once SO allows me.